# TypeOrm cascade: true doesn't remove it's relations from other table when I drop table from database

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

When I run DROP TABLE capability_tree cascade; it should remove all references to capability-trees from capabilities table...

**but it doesn't** here's how I have set up OneToOne relationship.

capability-tree.entity.ts

```
@Field(() => Capability)
@OneToOne(type => Capability, capability => capability.capability_tree)
capability: Capability;
```

capabilities.entity.ts

```
 @Field(() => CapabilityTree)
 @OneToOne(type => CapabilityTree, capabilityTree => capabilityTree.capability, { cascade: true })
 @JoinColumn({ name: 'capability_tree_id' })
 capability_tree: Capability
```

Based on my research `cascade: true` should delete all records from capabilities table if it references to capability_trees table after I delete record from capability_trees table, but if I'm mistaken please answer bellow. I hope I made myself clear and you understand what I want to achieve.

Comment: it will works only if typeorm will generate foreign key in table `capability` to table `capability_tree`, check your database, how does it looks like, then you will know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution! Turns out I have to add `nulalble: true` to @Field. It kinda makes sense, so my code would look like this

```
@Field(() => Capability, {nullable: true})
@OneToOne(type => Capability, capability => capability.capability_tree)
capability: Capability;

@Field(() => CapabilityTree, {nullable: true})
@OneToOne(type => CapabilityTree, capabilityTree => capabilityTree.capability, 
{ cascade: true })
@JoinColumn({ name: 'capability_tree_id' })
capability_tree: Capability
```